# Error 403 que sólo pasa con el término XHTML en el sitio

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, error-403

Tengo un problema en [mi sitio](https://www.glosarioit.com/) (les dejo la URL para que lo busquen y vean el error) que sólo se da cuando se busca el término **"XHTML"**. El sitio es un glosario informático y por ende el contenido muestra definición de términos. En este caso sólo necesito que me traiga el término **XHTML** y me muestre su definición. Pero como pueden comprobar no se muestra nada. Si veo el error en la consola dice que el **código de error es 403** y me pone la línea en `xmlHttp.send(null)` del archivo *ajax1.js*. Agregar también que **de manera local me funciona perfectamente**.

Acá me surgieron tres cosas:

1. Estuve averiguando un poco y haciendo cambios en dicho archivo (como hacerlo por *fetch* y no con *xhr*), pero sigue igual.
2. Después lo pense del lado del archivo PHP (*consulta.php*) en donde hace la consulta a la base de datos para traer la definición, pero no veo ningún error allí.
3. Este punto es el que creo más probable. Como el error 403 es
   que indica que se entendió la solicitud, pero no completará la solicitud porque el activo solicitado está "prohibido". Quizás el problema sea del servidor. Entonces pense en el archivo *.htaccess* con el `mod_security` y luego puse en dicho archivo lo siguiente:

```
  <IfModule mod_security.c>
   SecFilterEngine Off
   SecFilterScanPOST Off
  </IfModule>
```

pero esto tampoco solucionó el problema. A lo mejor me falta hacer algo más.

Lo importante a saber es que sólo pasa con ese término (**XHTML**), que por cierto estoy viendo si lo saco definitivamente de la base de datos ya que no es necesario que esté sino me va a mostrar nada.
Seguro que tiene que ver con la seguridad. Me gustaría que el servidor, o lo que sea, entienda que eso, en este caso **XHTML**, no es ninguna extensión o archivo malicioso. Es simplemente el nombre para traer su definición.

Aunque no lo quería poner (al ser un poco largo), les dejo el archivo `Consulta.php`. La variable `$Nombre` es la que guarda el término solicitado. En resumen, las consultas en este archivo *.php* son muy parecidas, cambiando sólo, según la tabla a buscar.
Este archivo hace consultas a la BD para el térimo solicitado según la sección (tabla) elegida por el usuario, sino se seleccionó ninguna, la búsqueda será completa en cada tabla.

Repito **dos cosas importantes**, con todos los términos funciona, salvo al buscar *XHTML*. Lo segundo; de manera local funciona todo, o sea, además de traer todo, también me muestra el término *XHTML*. Por eso no creo que el problema este en este archivo.

A continuación el archivo `Consulta.php`:

```
<?php
include("cni.php");
$Nombre=trim(isset($_GET['q']) ? $_GET['q'] : "");

function utf8Urldecode($Nombre)
{if (is_array($Nombre)){
        foreach ($Nombre as $key => $val) {
            $Nombre[$key] = utf8Urldecode($val);
        }
}
else {$Nombre=rawurldecode($Nombre);}
    return $Nombre;
  }

$Nombre=utf8Urldecode($Nombre);
$Cat=isset($_GET['cat']) ? $_GET['cat'] : "";
$Cant=0;
$ip=trim($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    switch($Cat){
        case 1:
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"select Descripcion,Palabra from abc where Palabra like ? or Alternativa like ? or Alternativa1 like ? or Alternativa2 like ? order by Palabra limit 1");
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'ssss',$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql,$Desc,$Pal);
         $Categoria='Informática';
         $Si=1;
        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)){
            $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
<section class="tblInf"><h1><?php echo $Pal ?> - Sección Informática</h1><div class="desc"><?php echo $Desc ?></div></section>
        <?php exit;
        }else{
            $Si=0;
            $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
    <p class="Descripcion"><span class="keyRojo">&raquo;</span>&nbsp;<?php echo 'El término <strong>'.htmlspecialchars($Nombre).'</strong> no se encuentra en la sección Informática.';?></p>
             <p class="Descripcion">Pruebe las siguientes 3 opciones:<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Verifique en otra sección.<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Escriba el término de nuevo pero no seleccione ninguna sección.<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Compruebe también, que el término este escrito correctamente y sin falta de ortografía.</p>
            <?php }
     mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
     mysqli_close($cxn);
     break;
    case 2:
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"select Descripcion,Palabra from redes where Palabra like ? or Alternativa like ? or Alternativa1 like ? or Alternativa2 like ? order by Palabra limit 1");
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'ssss',$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql,$Desc,$Pal);
         $Categoria='Redes';
         $Si=1;
        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)){
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
<section class="tblRed"><h1><?php echo $Pal ?> - Sección Redes</h1><div class="desc"><?php echo $Desc ?></div></section>
        <?php
         exit;}else{
             $Si=0;
             $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
        <p class="Descripcion"><span class="keyRojo">&raquo;</span>&nbsp;<?php echo 'El término <strong>'.htmlspecialchars($Nombre).'</strong> no se encuentra en la sección Redes.';?></p>
             <p class="Descripcion">Pruebe las siguientes 3 opciones:<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Verifique en otra sección.<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Escriba el término de nuevo pero no seleccione ninguna sección.<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Compruebe también, que el término este escrito correctamente y sin falta de ortografía.</p>
            <?php }
        mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
        mysqli_close($cxn);
        break;
    case 3:
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"select Descripcion,Palabra from multimedia where Palabra like ? or Alternativa like ? or Alternativa1 like ? or Alternativa2 like ? order by Palabra limit 1");
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'ssss',$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql,$Desc,$Pal);
         $Categoria='Multimedia';
         $Si=1;
        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)){
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
<section class="tblMul"><h1><?php echo $Pal ?> - Sección Multimedia</h1><div class="desc"><?php echo $Desc ?></div></section>
        <?php
        exit;}else{
            $Si=0;
             $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
        <p class="Descripcion"><span class="keyRojo">&raquo;</span>&nbsp;<?php echo 'El término <strong>'.htmlspecialchars($Nombre).'</strong> no se encuentra en la sección Multimedia.';?></p>
             <p class="Descripcion">Pruebe las siguientes 3 opciones:<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Verifique en otra sección.<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Escriba el término de nuevo pero no seleccione ninguna sección.<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Compruebe también, que el término este escrito correctamente y sin falta de ortografía.</p>
            <?php }
        mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
        mysqli_close($cxn);
        break;
    case 4:
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"select Descripcion,Palabra from bdprogramacion where Palabra like ? or Alternativa like ? or Alternativa1 like ? or Alternativa2 like ? order by Palabra limit 1");
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'ssss',$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql,$Desc,$Pal);
         $Categoria='BD/Programacion';
         $Si=1;
        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)){
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
<section class="tblBD"><h1><?php echo $Pal ?> - Sección BD/Programación</h1><div class="desc"><?php echo $Desc ?></div></section>
        <?php
        exit;}else{
            $Si=0;
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$row['Palabra'],$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
             <p class="Descripcion"><span class="keyRojo">&raquo;</span>&nbsp;<?php echo 'El término <strong>'.htmlspecialchars($Nombre).'</strong> no se encuentra en la sección BD/Programación.';?></p>
             <p class="Descripcion">Pruebe las siguientes 3 opciones:<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Verifique en otra sección.<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Escriba el término de nuevo pero no seleccione ninguna sección.<br>
                <span class="keyAzul">• </span>Compruebe también, que el término este escrito correctamente y sin falta de ortografía.</p>
            <?php }
        mysqli_stmt_close($sql);
        mysqli_close($cxn);
        break;
    case "":
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"select Descripcion,Palabra from abc where Palabra like ? or Alternativa like ? or Alternativa1 like ? or Alternativa2 like ? order by Palabra limit 1");
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'ssss',$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql,$Desc,$Pal);
         $Categoria='Sin sección';
         $Si=1;
        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)){
            $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
<section class="tblInf"><h1><?php echo $Pal ?> - Sección Informática</h1><div class="desc"><?php echo $Desc ?></div></section>
          <?php mysqli_stmt_close($sql);}else{$Cant=$Cant+1;}
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"select Descripcion,Palabra from redes where Palabra like ? or Alternativa like ? or Alternativa1 like ? or Alternativa2 like ? order by Palabra limit 1");
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'ssss',$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql,$Desc,$Pal);
        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)){
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
<section class="tblRed"><h1><?php echo $Pal ?> - Sección Redes</h1><div class="desc"><?php echo $Desc ?></div></section>
    <?php mysqli_stmt_close($sql);}else{$Cant=$Cant+1;}
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"select Descripcion,Palabra from multimedia where Palabra like ? or Alternativa like ? or Alternativa1 like ? or Alternativa2 like ? order by Palabra limit 1");
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'ssss',$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql,$Desc,$Pal);
        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)){
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
<section class="tblMul"><h1><?php echo $Pal ?> - Sección Multimedia</h1><div class="desc"><?php echo $Desc ?></div></section>
    <?php mysqli_stmt_close($sql);}else{$Cant=$Cant+1;}
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"select Descripcion,Palabra from bdprogramacion where Palabra like ? or Alternativa like ? or Alternativa1 like ? or Alternativa2 like ? order by Palabra limit 1");
         mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'ssss',$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre,$Nombre);
         mysqli_stmt_execute($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_store_result($sql);
         mysqli_stmt_bind_result($sql,$Desc,$Pal);
        if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($sql)){
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
<section class="tblBD"><h1><?php echo $Pal ?> - Sección BD/Programación</h1><div class="desc"><?php echo $Desc ?></div></section>
     <?php mysqli_stmt_close($sql);mysqli_close($cxn);}else{$Cant=$Cant+1;}
        if ($Cant==4 && $Nombre!=''){
            $Si=0;
        $sql=mysqli_prepare($cxn,"Insert into estadistica Values (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($sql,'sssssi',$ip,$Nombre,$Pal,$fecha2,$Categoria,$Si);
            if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($sql)) {die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($cxn));}?>
        <p class="Descripcion"><?php echo 'El término <strong>'.htmlspecialchars($Nombre).'</strong> no existe en GlosarioIT o fue ingresado de manera incorrecta, verifíquelo.';?></p><p class="Descripcion"><span class="keyBD">»</span> También, puedes consultar nuestra <a href="/ContenidoIT.php" class="enlace2" rel="nofollow">lista completa de términos</a> (buscando allí por categoría, o bien, de manera completa).</p>
  <?php mysqli_stmt_close($sql);mysqli_close($cxn);}}?>
```

Comment: No podremos ayudarte si no muestras el código de servidor que gestiona la respuesta para mandarla de vuelta al cliente. Puede que ese código por ejemplo haga verificaciones del tipo: *si en el contenido está la palabra `XHTML` devuelve un error 403 como respuesta*. Es sólo por imaginar algo, pero estamos ante un problema, generado por un código, entonces, muestra ese código, de lo contrario, sólo podremos imaginar posibles errores. Algo muy recomendable en caso de errores es verificar el log de errores... Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: @A.Cedano No tengo acceso a dicho código, al menos eso creo. Tengo el cPanel para ver, pero no creo que este habilitado para ver eso. Imagino que estará restringido. Con el tema del archivo log, ya lo busque dentro de *public_html\error_log* y no aparece nada allí como error.

Comment: A ver, ¿acaso el archivo php que falla no está en alguna parte en `public_html`? En el mismo cPanel suele haber un navegador de archivos donde puedes acceder a todos los archivos que te pertenecen, sea que estés en un hosting compartido, en un VPS, etc. Desde ahí podrás abrir el archivo `.php` y corregir los errores que tengas, aunque realmente no es lo mejor, si vas a editar archivos remotos lo mejor es usar un cliente que te permita navegar por tu servidor y demás, pero cuidando la seguridad, usando por ejemplo llaves públicas y privadas ... bueno, ese es otro asunto...

Comment: La cuestión es que, no debe ser cierto que no tengas acceso a ese archivo, a no ser que por algún motivo esté en una carpeta protegida, fuera de tu alcance, en cuyo caso tendrás que contactar a personal autorizado para que corrija el error. En cuanto a la ubicación de log de errores, casi nunca se encuentra en `public_html` directamente. Según el hosting, lo suelen poner en cada carpeta donde está el script php que genera el error, o suele ser un solo archivo que guarda todos los errores.

Comment: @A.Cedano No sé a que archivo php específicamente te refieres. Yo desde el Administrador de archivos del cPanel estoy viendo todas las carpetas y archivos, pero como ya dije en la pregunta, el archivo Consulta.php, en donde está la consulta a la BD está bien, no hay error. Y los errores de php por ejemplo, los va tirando en el que dije (error_log) y ahi mismo están los otros archivos: index.php, Consulta.php, etc.

Comment: Me refiero a `Consulta.php`. ¿No tienes acceso a ese archivo? No des por hecho que el archivo *está bien*, puede haber algo mal en él y necesitamos verlo.